# Unknown white space inside SwiftUI which can't display any element on top of it

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is a white space inside my SwiftUI View which is not filled out properly. In that white space area, there is nothing that I can display on top of it.
I tried putting a red border around each element one by one, and I found out that the white space belongs to ZStack.

However, I still could not get rid of it. How to deal with this problem?

Below are my code and reference picture:

[unknown white space image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZTz6.jpg)

```
struct ForTest: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .background(.white)
            }
            .border(.red)
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(1...15, id: \.self) {_ in
                        Text("Hello, World")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a `.background` modifier on the Rectangle, when you are using the `.fill` method? And a `.border(red)` on the ZStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting `.frame(height: 300)` **after** the `.background(.white)`, and of course remove `.frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are a lot of things to remove.

- You might need to get rid of the border on the ZStack.
- background modifier from the Rectangle.
- Also you have to fix the frame modifier on the rectangle. You need to remove `.infinity` from the width as said in the response https://stackoverflow.com/a/72581341/17708926. You need to replace it with maxWidth and maxWidth arguments. then set both to `.infinity`. This will fix the problem.

[image: fixed screenshot]

Comment: Your solution worked, but then my Rectangle() could not work dynamically due to the fixed height as I needed to do some animation after that. However, appreciated for the new knowledge.